# Why does my shell produce a `Error: Cannot find module 'commander'`

Tags: node.js

Everytime a new shell is opened, it outputs

`Error: Cannot find module 'commander'`

My question is..

Why is the shell in need of a 'commander'?
Why does it even try to look for that?

I've done `npm i -g commander`
And yet, the commander is still missing in action.

`Error: Cannot find module 'commander'`

How is it possible to get rid of this annoying message?

Comment: Maybe your shell startup file invokes a node script? Which shell are you using?